# How to enable the bar showing file location in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

I want to enable the "navigation"  bar that is supposed to just below the tabs in the editor. It shows what the file hierarchy is. For example if you had a HelloWorld project it shows:
HelloWorld -> src -> SomeClass.java -> main
And all the different locations are clickable. I know you can use the double arrows to link what is in the editor to the resource in the package explorer.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Additionally to the shortcut in the answer from Eli, there is a button in your toolbar: [image: breadcrumps]

Answer (score 39):

This feature is called *breadcrumbs*. From [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-breadcrumb.htm):

> To enable the breadcrumb invoke Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb in the
>   toolbar or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in the Java editor.
>
> The enablement of the breadcrumb is remembered for each perspective. The breadcrumb can for example be enabled in the debug perspective and be disabled in the Java perspective.

Comment: @tgkprog I don't know, but you can try to open the Preferences dialog, go to General --> Keys and check the "Binding" column for "Show In Breadcrumb". If you post your findings here, I'll update the answer.

Comment: The preference is where you say it is, but it seems its always on in Mac. Using Luna 4.4.1

Comment: @tgkprog Is there a keyboard shortcut for it on Mac?

Comment: @EliAcherkan alt+cmd+b for Mac

Comment: @tgkprog alt+cmd+b for Mac

Comment: It is working only for the java files not for the other files like ftl,css,js