# Eclipse: How can I close this bar?

Tags: eclipse

How can I close this bar (marked red)?
And how is it called?

[image]

I don't know how I opened it, and I can't find the option to close it again...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: breadcrumb bar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952614/how-to-enable-the-bar-showing-file-location-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can right-click on any icon on the breadcrumb, and select the entry named "Hide Breadcrumb".

[image]

or

Find the file `org.eclipse.help.webapp\advanced\breadcrumbs.css` and replace its contents with.

```
.help_breadcrumbs {
   display: none;
}
```