# What is this view called in Eclipse and how to open it?

Tags: java, eclipse

On Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 I have this view that shows nicely the hierarchy of the file opened in the editor: [image: View] . (The perspective used here is Java EE)

I have now moved to Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen, and I can't find this view anywhere. I would really like to activate it again.
Does anybody knows what it is called and how to activate it? Also, does it have maybe something to do with Java EE? Because on Eclipse Oxygen I use the perspective Java.

Comment: The duplicate is about disabling it, but it still answer your questions ;)

Comment: Thanks, I had looked for it but didn't know it was called "breadcrumbs"!

Comment: Me neither. I did use https://www.google.com/search?q=java+eclipse+file+path+toggle to find this question

Comment: Well done, you are better at googling than I am then. Found this other question which answers Enable and not Disable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952614/how-to-enable-the-bar-showing-file-location-in-eclipse

Comment: I was just lucky :) I did add the question you found to the list of duplicates (for futur reader)