# Eclipse IDE - What are breadcrumbs, and how do I disable them?

Tags: eclipse, ide

[image]

Due to a mistake, I opened up the breadcrumbs bar. What are they, and how do I disable them?

Comment: CMD Z? CTRL Z??

Comment: Doesn't remove it... I'm pretty sure that only works for code edits

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952614/how-to-enable-the-bar-showing-file-location-in-eclipse) answer.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Thanks, this worked.
Feel free to write an answer